# Executing PHP code from DB

Tags: php, database

This question has been asked multiple times before,
but I have a different situation from those I've read.

My Database multiple forms that are to be loaded upon user request. This is not the problem and I can handle this. Within these forms, there are fields that are filled dynamically from 2 queries.

One of my fields that is to be filled from the database looks like this:

```
<label class="itemLabel" for="name">Name : </label>
    <input name="name" type="text" class="itemInput" value="<? echo $queryB[1]; ?>" readonly="readonly" />
```

as you can see, the value is set to be a PHP code `echo $queryB[1]` ... When I got the form from the DB and echoed it, the fields got the value `<? echo $queryB[1]; ?>` instead of the actual value.

I've tried to use `eval($myForm)` where my form is retrieved from the DB, but nothing appeared in the place where the form should appear. I would appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: You should really be putting a placeholder in the value attribute that you can then replace in code after loading from the database. Your solution forces you to place PHP variable names in the database, which would be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: @cbuckley: I don't think this script will be maintained, it will work as is. Also it is for non-technical users, and I'm the one responsible for it. Can you specify how to put a placeholder in the value attribue then replace it later?

Comment: just put it in the `placeholder=` attribute in the HTML. Now, wouldn't it be simpler to save the **value you want** in the database rather then the **code to how to get to the value you want**?

Comment: In the future, even though you're responsible for the script, you will be able to remember these details?

Comment: "I don't think this script will be maintained" - ahahah, the most funny statement

Comment: @GabrielSantos: I 'm having everything documented.

Comment: I don't want to start a religious war here, but the "I don't think this script will be maintained" isn't always crazy... taking 30 minutes to write a script that could take 15 minutes if you don't bother with certain formalities makes sense if there is a 90% chance that you'll never need to come back to the project. The key is knowing what that chance is, and not taking shortcuts when shortcuts make the script so unreadable that it will take forever to rebuild if you are unfortunate enough to run into that 10% scenario.

Comment: @Truth: The problem is, I have around 20 forms, most of them use common data, which is saved in the database. So all I wanted to do, is have the form itself stored in the database and then loaded with all the attributes.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: What is funny about that?!! I'm the one who created the script and I'm the one who knows what it will require!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on my comment and Col Shrapnel's answer, here is a simple placeholder example. You should really maintain the HTML in a flat file (as it effectively seems to be part of the view in your application), but for simplicity's sake let's say it still resides in the database. Store the following value:

```
<label class="itemLabel" for="name">Name : </label>
<input name="name" type="text" class="itemInput" value="{queryValue}" readonly="readonly" />
```

Now, when you load the value from the database, you can replace the placeholder from the text:

```
$html = str_replace('{queryValue}', $queryB[1], $htmlTemplate);
```

This is an incredibly simplified example, and masks a load of potential issues regarding placeholder names, formats etc., but it might get you started.

---

Alternatively, if you decide to opt for the file route, you could have two files:

**view.phtml**:

```
<label class="itemLabel" for="name">Name : </label>
<input name="name" type="text" class="itemInput" value="<?php echo $this->value; ?>" readonly="readonly" />
```

**In your current PHP script**:

```
class View {
    public function render($file) {
        // check for file existence etc.
        require_once $file;
    }
}

$view = new View();
$view->value = $queryB[1];
$view->render('view.phtml');
```

Comment: both approaches are great. Yet, I have many fields that are populated from the database, so neither will be helpful. I'm thinking of taking all my forms out of the DB as they are and add them to a `switch` in a separate file then `include` the file within the page. Is this good enough?

Comment: I've choose your answer as it is the closest to what I'm achieving now

Comment: Both these solutions allow for you to populate multiple placeholders / variables in the same script. If you have lots of different HTML fragments, then yes you can put them in separate files and simply include the relevant one. You could store the name of the file to include in the database to avoid the switch statement

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP instance has [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) disabled.

Change it to:

```
<?php echo $queryB[1]; ?>
```

...and it should do what you expect.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, this is from my php.ini file `short_open_tag = On`

Comment: @Dave: I'm very interested in hearing how'd you get to that conclusion :o

Comment: @Truth He says that his field is populated with `<? echo $queryB[1]; ?>` as a literal value - this is a classic sign of PHP ignoring a short open tag. I could be wrong, but it seems *very* likely this is the problem...

Comment: It seems PHP's short_open_tag are off, if is off, every time the value will be interpreted as HTML

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question (I though he was saving the `<?...?>` part in the database, rather then the actual value, and that's why it's... whatever, +1.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing different in your situation and it is exactly the same as others.

and the answer is the same as well: **do not mix the code and the data**.
Do not store the code in the database.
<s>Do not pass GO, do not collect $200</s>
Implement some sort of placeholders or - even better - some form builder  and create these forms on the fly, based on the data from database.

Why not to store only relevant data in the database, like
name
type
value
class
and some flags like disabled, readonly and such?

take a look at http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm2/